# How do I make it possible to only check one of two checkboxes in ASP.NET MVC using models and controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have an online form which the applicants need to fill in. Some of the options is to check whether they are applying as multilateral or bilateral, and I am not sure how to make this happen in ASP.NET MVC?

I know I have to code it in a manner so that when one of them is checked, the other will be unchecked (i.e. setting the other to false when one is checked)

I tried doing so by using an id in the create.cshtml file and then included some code in the controller but did not work, because I am not sure how to include the attributes(?).

Could you please help me? I am sure it is just me being a newbie and not really that difficult.

below is from the razor pages

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Multilateral, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div ID="chkMu" oncecheckedchanged="chkMu_CheckedChanged" class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Multilateral)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Multilateral, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bilateral, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div ID="chkBi" oncecheckedchanged="chkBi_CheckedChanged" class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bilateral)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bilateral, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

below is from the controller

```
protected void chkBi_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, object chkMu)
{
    chkMu.Checked = false;
}

protected void chkMu_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, object ckhBi)
{
    chkBi.Checked = false;
}
```

I also found some code online which suggested writing it in javascript and using jQuery, but I do not know how to implement it still. Below is the code

```
$('div .checkbox').click(function () {
    var checkedState = $(this).prop("checked")
    $(this)
        .parent('div')
        .children('.checkbox:checked')
        .prop("checked", false);

    $(this).prop("checked", checkedState);
});
```

really appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo with jquery:

View:

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Lead">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Multilateral, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div oncecheckedchanged="chkMu_CheckedChanged" >
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkMu" name="chkMu"/>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Multilateral)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Multilateral, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bilateral, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div oncecheckedchanged="chkBi_CheckedChanged">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkBi" name="chkBi"/>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bilateral)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bilateral, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

jquery:

```
@section scripts{

    <script>
        $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
            if (this.checked&&this.id == "chkMu")
            {
                $('#chkBi').prop('checked', false);
            } else if (this.checked && this.id == "chkBi")
            {
                $('#chkMu').prop('checked', false);
            }
        })
    </script>
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Ok wow thank you so much! This was really helpful. Only thing is I have to implement it in c# in VS, and using the <script>code</script> dont work, I have to figure out how to use @Scripts.Render or something, but I will challenge myself to try and figure it out. Thank you for the great demo!

Comment: Try to add <script></script> to `@section scripts {}`.I have updated my js  in my answer.And if my answer is helpful,can you accept it as answer?Thank you.

Comment: just one more thing, doing this makes it look good, but now that they have chosen one of them, the result is not stored in the database table as it's not connected to the model?

Comment: If you can get it in your action,it means model binding is right.And if you want to store it to database.it is another question,you need to add it to your database by yourself.Here is a link about [efcore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0).